# RMI without stubs

Tags: java, web, rmi

Given the following note:
(found [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/rmi/hello/hello-world.html#21))

> Note: As of the J2SE 5.0 release, stub classes for remote objects no
>   longer need to be pregenerated using the rmic stub compiler, unless
>   the remote object needs to support clients running in pre-5.0 VMs. If
>   your application needs to support such clients, you will need to
>   generate stub classes for the remote objects used in the application
>   and deploy those stub classes for clients to download. For details on
>   how to generate stub classes, see the tools documentation for rmic
>   [Solaris, Windows]. For details on how to deploy your application
>   along with pregenerated stub classes, see the codebase tutorial.

My question is simple:
How does RMI work without stubs ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It generates them dynamically using `java.lang.reflect.Proxy.` See the class preamble to the Javadoc for `java.rmi.server.UnicastRemoteObject.`

Comment: And what does rmiregistry need to know if it doesn't need to know the stubs ?

Comment: It needs the remote interface .class, and all classes it depends on, and so on until closure. Same as the client.